# Wait a signal with timeout , if the signal is received just continue the execution (no action associated to the signal)

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

i'm trying to wait for a signal with a timeout.
I'm implementing a keep alive functionality for a distributed hash table. A server can be connected to other servers and it need to know if a connected server had a problem and is no longer connected.

Here the first function that will send a signal if a server is still alive.

```
void sendSignalKeepAlive(struct server *serverTable,unsigned int *serverCursor,struct server *s)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < *serverCursor; i++)
  {
    if( strcmp((char*)serverTable[i].ip,(char*)s->ip)==0 && serverTable[i].port==s->port)
    {
      pthread_kill(serverTable[i].keepAlive,SIGUSR1);
    }
  }
}
```

And then the other function associated to a thread associated to a server, which wait for a signal to know if the server is alive. If the thread does not receive the signal before a defined time the thread delete the server and then end. If the thread receive the signal it will just loop and wait for another signal.

```
void *keepAlive(void *s)
{
  struct keepAliveThread *kat = (keepAliveThread*)s;

  //prepare the signal handler for our thread that will indicate that the server is alive, and prepare the timeout that indicate that the server is dead
  sigset_t mask;
    struct timespec timeout;
  sigemptyset (&mask);
    sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR1);

  timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;


  while(1)
  {
    int sig = sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeout);
    printf("SIG VALUE%d\n",sig);
    if( sig < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) //timeout: the server is dead
        {
          printf("Timeout server with ip %s and port %u \n",kat->serv->ip,kat->serv->port);
                deleteServer(kat->serverTable,kat->serverCursor,kat->serv,kat->serverTableSize);
          pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
            }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("SIGNAL RECEIVED %d\n",sig);
      printf("Receive keep alive from server ip %s and port %u\n",kat->serv->ip,kat->serv->port);
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible ? I just wanted to send a signal with no action associated but i can't find how to do it.

[updated] SIGUSR1 give me **User defined signal 1** and then it end the thread. I changed the signal send from SIGINFO to SIGUSR1 of the displayed code in this topic,i was doing test and i forget to change it before pasting it on this topic, sorry for my mistake. But i'm still wondering if it is possible to send a signal to tell my thread to continue its execution without ending it.

Comment: Have you looked into Semaphores? I guess counting semaphore should resolve what you are looking for.

Comment: I think these [examples](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-2:-Counting-Semaphores) fits in your case.

Comment: Yeah this could be a good alternative aswell, i wanted to try signal first because it implies less arguments for the threads. I already have few structure and i didn't wanted to add more field or to create new structures. But if i really can't solve my problem i will try semaphore with mutex and conditions.

Comment: "*`pthread_cancel(pthread_self());`*": why not jut call `pthread_exit();`?

Comment: The code sends `SIGINFO`? The code waits for `SIGUSR1`?

Comment: Sorry i was doing test and i forget to change SIGINFO for SIGUSR1. SIGINFO was declared as undefined by gcc and SIGUSR1 was terminating my thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the thread `keepAlive()`, you have to block the signal the thread is waitig for using `pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);` before the while loop.

If the signal isn't blocked, then the signal will have the default behaviour on the program, so SIGUSR1 will end the program.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_t server1,server2,ka1,ka2;

void deleteServer(pthread_t server) {
  pthread_cancel(server);
}

void sendSignalKeepAlive(pthread_t server)
{
  pthread_kill(server,SIGUSR1);
}


void *keepAlive(void *s)
{
  pthread_t server = *((pthread_t*)s);

  char * servername;
  if(server == server1) servername = "server1";
  else if(server == server2) servername = "server2";

  sigset_t mask;
  sigemptyset (&mask);
  sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR1);
  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Here SIGUSR1 is blocked for this thread:
  ////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);

  struct timespec timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 10;
  timeout.tv_nsec = 0;


  while(1)
  {
    int sig = sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeout);
    printf("SIG VALUE%d\n",sig);
    if( sig < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) //timeout: the server is dead
        {
          printf("Timeout %s\n",servername);
                deleteServer(server);
          pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
            }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("SIGNAL RECEIVED %d\n",sig);
      printf("Receive keep alive from %s\n",servername);
    }
  }
}


void * server_thread( void * data) {
  while(1) {
    sleep(2);
    sendSignalKeepAlive(ka1);
    sendSignalKeepAlive(ka2);
  }
}


int main() {
  pthread_create(&server1,NULL,server_thread,NULL);
  pthread_create(&server2,NULL,server_thread,NULL);
  pthread_create(&ka1,NULL,keepAlive,&server1);
  pthread_create(&ka2,NULL,keepAlive,&server2);

  pthread_join(ka1,NULL);
  pthread_join(ka2,NULL);
  pthread_join(server1,NULL);
  pthread_join(server2,NULL);
}
```